# Why is this Typescript export undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a NPM package using Typescript and React. (TSX)

I am following [this blog post](https://medium.com/@jchiam/publishing-a-typescript-react-component-to-npm-d3cc15b8d0a2), but trying to make multiple components instead of just one.

When I try and import my module like this

```
import { HelloWorld } from 'tsx_lib'
```

It shows up as undefined

```
console.log(HelloWorld) //undefined
```

My folder structure looks like this

```
src /
   GoodbyeWorld.tsx
   HelloWorld.tsx
   index.ts
index.d.ts
```

Here are the files

**GoodbyeWorld.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { GoodbyeWorldProps } from '../index';

export default class GoodbyeWorld extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return <div style={{ color: this.props.color }}>Goodbye world!</div>;
  }
}
```

**HelloWorld.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { HelloWorldProps } from '../index';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return <div style={{ color: this.props.color }}>Hello world!</div>;
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './HelloWorld';
export * from './GoodbyeWorld';
```

**index.d.ts**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface HelloWorldProps extends React.Props<HelloWorld> {
  color: string;
}

export interface GoodbyeWorldProps extends React.Props<HelloWorld> {
  color: string;
}

declare module 'hello-world' {

}

declare module 'goodbye-world' {

}

export class HelloWorld extends React.Component<HelloWorldProps, any> {}
export class GoodbyeWorld extends React.Component<HelloWorldProps, any> {}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: try `import HelloWorld from 'tsx_lib'` without brackets, if you export it as `default` module, you need to import it without brackets

Comment: But I'm not trying to export it as default, I want to be able to access both HelloWorld and GoodbyeWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export default class HelloWorld` in `HelloWorld.tsx` is a default export.

`export * from './HelloWorld'` will not pass through default exports.

You have two options:

1. export named from `HelloWorld.tsx`

```
export class HelloWorld extends Component { 
...
```

2. map the default export to a named export

```
export { default as HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld'
```